# Select state in view picker, go to new screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview, picker

I'm coding an app in XCode using Swift, and I currently have a list picker on the app. I want the user to be able to select a state from the picker view, which would take them to a new screen (designed for that specific state).

User interface:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### METHOD 1:

**NOTE:** This is to be used if you have one view controller which has to be customized...

---

*Try this:*

**STEP 1:** On your `View Controller` add this variable:

```
var chosenState = String()
```

**STEP 2:** Add this function to the `View Controller`:

```
override func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
chosenState = yourPickerData[row] // yourPickerData = your state array
}
```

**STEP 3:** If you have a segue connected to the button, delete it. Do the following things on the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Choose the **Show** Connection, click the segue and set its identifier to `customSegue`, as in the picture above.

**STEP 4:** Inside the **continue** button function in the view controller, add this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("customSegue", sender: nil)
```

**STEP 5:** Add the `prepareForSegue` method in your `ViewController`:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "customSegue" {
            if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? secondViewController {
                secondViewController.customLabel.text = self.chosenState
// this is an example, but the view will contain the name of the chosen state by the time the button gets clicked... You can customize it...
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps! Let me know what you think!

### METHOD 2:

**NOTE:** This is to be used if you have created more `View Controllers` in storyboard.

---

*Try this:*

### INTERAFACE:

**STEP 1:** Go to your `Storyboard` and add a button onto the scene, below the `pickerView`, as shown in the image below, and make sure that the class of your View Controller is actually set to `ViewController.swift`:
[image]

**STEP 2:** Open up the Assistant Editor and connect the button by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click and drag to the `ViewController.swift`, as shown below:

[image]
[image]

The connection type: **Action**, name it however you like. After you connect it, this will appear:

```
@IBAction func continueButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject?){
//this is your continue button function
}
```

**NOTE:** For Tutorial Purposes, I am only going to work with 3 States!

**STEP 3:** Drag three `View Controllers`(Or as many as you like) onto the scene, and then add three(or as many as you want) swift files called StateName View Controller to your project. Add this code to them:

```
import UIKit

    class StateNameViewController: UIViewController{

    }
```

1:
[image]
 2:
[image]
 3:
[image]
 4:
[image]

**STEP 4:** Assign their classes, like so:

Select the first `ViewController` on the `storyboard`, go to the **Identity Inspector** and set its class to `AlabamaViewController`. And like so to the other 2.

**STEP 5:** Then create a segue for each one and set its identifier to State Name Segue, like so:

How to do it for the first one:
[image]
The other 2:
[image]

**STEP 6:** Connect the `pickerView` with the code like so:

[image]

### CODE:

**STEP 7:** Go to your ViewController and add this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData = ["Alabama","Alaska","Kansas"]
    var chosenState = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

**STEP 8:** Inside`ViewController.swift`, add these functions:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    //Called when the user changes the selection...
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        chosenState = pickerData[row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
    }
```

**STEP 9:** The Button Function with code added:

```
@IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(chosenState)Segue", sender: nil)

}
```

### PREVIEW - METHOD 2:

**The ViewController.swift in the end:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData = ["Alabama","Alaska","Kansas"]
    var chosenState = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(chosenState)Segue", sender: nil)

    }


    // The number of columns of data


    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    //Called when the user changes the selection...
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        chosenState = pickerData[row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
    }


}
```

This is it! Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I'm still having trouble at step three of the second method. This sounds silly, but I don't think I have a continue button function and I'm not sure how to write one?

Comment: @B.Myles I have updated the answer. Please let me know if it is effective for you. For me it just works perfectly. NOTE: Please do what I say for one of the methods, step by step from the begging till the end, 'cause if you don't, you might need to start all over again...

Comment: I strongly recommend Method 1, because the work is done programmatically with only one ViewController. But if you are a begginer method 2 will help you start. Note: Method 2 needs as many VC-s as your states Array contains...

Comment: If it helps, make sure to press that check button above

Comment: I keep getting an error when I go to put in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(chosenState)Segue", sender: nil) in the button function. The error says "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member in 'performanceSegue'". Again, thank you for all your help.

Comment: that's because you have written performanceSegue instead of performSegue

Comment: I don't understand, where did I write performanceSegue instead of performSegue?

Comment: in the continue button function

Comment: This is the code I currently have in the continue button function:     @IBAction func continueButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "\(chosenState)Segue", sender: nil)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, i hope you have a continue button after the user select the state, because if dont you can cause frustration to the user changing his mind about the selected state, anyway, you can catch the selected state with the function `pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)`, with this you will get the row selected, with that you can use it as a variable to determine the next view controller in the continue button, with a switch or something like this `switch selectedIndex{ 
case 0:
performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", self)
default:
print("No valid index selected")
}`